# Are numerical solutions appropriate for inference (eg, estimating variance for confidence intervals)?

Tags: derivative, numerics

For a nicely differentiable objective function, we traditionally always derive the gradients to use for e.g. estimating the variance. (1) Is it common nowadays to use numerical rather than analytical gradients this?  I know it is slower (for the computer at least), of course, but would the coverages be reasonable?  (2) Are there any general results on whether this is a good idea?  I know that in many cases the answer would be that it depends, but what if there is a very complex objective that would be difficult to differentiate by hand - can we use numerical gradients and sleep soundly?

Update: I learned just now that there is a distinction between eg autodiff and finite difference, and that the former is exact up to machine epsilon. I guess I was thinking along the lines of the state of the art (so I guess autodiff). R's `numDeriv` package uses numerical differentiation, but with Richardson's extrapolation.  R's `deriv` uses autodiff.

Comment: Numerical derivatives of complicated functions are more likely to be correct. It Is easy to make a mistake in analytical expressions of derivatives

Comment: Depends on what you mean by numerical gradient. Is it an approximation (e.g. finite differencing) or auto-diff (which is by now probably the most common) which gives you exact gradients (up to numerical precision). These are not the things to lose sleep to in the world of computational statistics

Comment: Thank you both, wow.  I did not even know that auto-diff gives exact gradients.